# Python Looping through File and downloading Images

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a text file with different website links to download the images. I also want them to have a unique file name. Just a loop counter as you see so the three images would be `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`. Yet I am only getting the last image and the file is named `0.jpg`. I have tried a couple of different methods but this seemed the best but still no luck. Any suggestions on next steps?

```
import urllib
input_file = open('Urls1.txt','r')
x=0
for line in input_file:
    URL= line

urllib.urlretrieve(URL, str(x) + ".jpg")
x+=1
```

Comment: indent the last two lines to match `URL= line`

Comment: VTC as this is caused by a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite the code by indenting the last two lines thus

```
import urllib
input_file = open('Urls1.txt','r')
x=0
for line in input_file:
    URL= line

    urllib.urlretrieve(URL, str(x) + ".jpg")
    x+=1
```

Indentation is significant in Python. Without it, the last two statements are only executed after the loop has completed. Thus you only retrieve the last URL in the file.